# Using result of javascript query as input for HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, axure

Is it possible to directly use the result of a Javascript function as an input value for an HTML form?

```
<form class="my-form" action="fileUpload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="User_id" value="getValue();">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

This is clearly not correct, but I hope it communicates what I am trying to do. I would like the returned result of JS function getValue(); to act as the input value.

Comment: Do you want to set a value with JavaScript?

Comment: Yes - In my specific case I built a webapp using Axure (prototyping tool) and using a javascript function is the only way I know how to access the local Axure variables.

Answer (score 1):

In that implementation, no it is not possible to equate the `value` attribute inside the `input` tag to a JavaScript function.

According to [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.text.html#input.text.attrs.value), the value attribute can only equal

> String without line breaks
>
> Any string that contains no line feed
>   (U+000A, “LF”) or carriage return (U+000D, “CR”) characters.

I am not sure what is inside the `getValue()` function, but you can call a click event handler when the submit button is clicked and run that `getValue()` function.

Ex.

```
<form class="my-form" action="fileUpload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="User_id">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="getValue();"/>
</form>
```

I hope it guides you well.

Comment: Thanks! The "getValue();" function simply returns a number. In your suggestion, the function is being called, but what I really need is for the returned value of that function to serve as the value for the User_id input, which I don't think is happening in your response.

Comment: I see, then what you can do is what JonSG has suggested below, after adding a click event listener, set the value of `input[name='User_id']` to 'getValue();'

Answer (score 0):

While it is technically possible to do something like this:

```
<script>
  function getValue(){ return "foo"; }
  document.write("<input type='hidden' name='User_id' value='" + getValue() + "' />");
</script>
```

That is typically frowned upon as there are scoping issues and page rendering implications.  The more accepted way would be to do something more like this..

```
function getValue(){ return "bar"; }

window.addEventListener("load", function(event){
    document.querySelector("input[name='User_id']").value = getValue();
});
```

or potentially at form submit or submit button click with something like:

```
function getValue(){ return "bar"; }

document.querySelector("input[type='submit']").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector("input[name='User_id']").value = getValue();
});
```

Though I am not keen on it myself, it would be possible to do the same as above with:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="setUserId();"/>
```

Then later in say a end of body script block do:

```
function getValue(){ return "bar"; }

function setUserId(){
    document.querySelector("input[name='User_id']").value = getValue();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - In regard to your last suggestion, where would I place that in my code? Directly after the submit button declaration, still inside the form?

Also, would this update the value for "User_ID" before the form was executed in the fileUpload.php file?

Comment: I would place it at the bottom on the body myself.  I try to keep scripting out of what might be thought of as the "rest of the html".  If you want a more "inline" option, I'll update with a 4th block...

Comment: Gotcha. So would I start by declaring this as blank:

<input type="hidden" name="User_id" value=""> and having the event listener update the value on the triggered submit button click?

Comment: @Jwarzy72 Ya, exactly.  You might even set it to something like "IdNotSet" then test for that server side (or test for "" if you would rather)